# ls list files with multiple sizes

Tags: command-line, ls

In the case we have some files with different sizes: for example one files smaller than 1 Mb and others bigger than 1 MB for example.

If I use `ls -l --block-size=M` it will show all files with less value of 1 MB with 1 MB. So it could be useful list the files with two different columns one with MB and other with KB.

I've tested `ls -l --block-size=M --block-size=K` but it lists the size by the last argument.

Is it possible to list multiples block sizes?

Comment: The `--block-size` option (at least in GNU `ls`) only scales the displayed size of files. It does not filter out files that are less in size. Can you provide example output in command line and paste it in to your question ? Which OS version are you using ?

Comment: If you are trying to list files with "automatically" scaled , to show one file with `k` and another with `M`, then use `ls -l -h`. (Let me know if you want this as full answer)

Comment: OK, will post in  couple minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display size of files scaled to the nearest [binary prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix), use `-h` flag ( same as `--human-readable` long option ):

```
$ ls -l -h
total 3.4M
-rwxrwxr-x 1 xieerqi xieerqi  223 3月   5 16:32 find_dir.pl*
drwxrwxr-x 3 xieerqi xieerqi 4.0K 3月   5 13:26 levelone/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 3.4M 3月   7 11:57 XUf6uMr.jpg
```

Same information, but in [powers of 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) can be displayed with `--si` option:

```
$ ls -l --si                                                                                                             
total 3.6M
-rwxrwxr-x 1 xieerqi xieerqi  223 3月   5 16:32 find_dir.pl*
drwxrwxr-x 3 xieerqi xieerqi 4.1k 3月   5 13:26 levelone/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 3.6M 3月   7 11:57 XUf6uMr.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `ls -lh`. This shows "human readable" sizes.